# Fetching SQL table data into a nested dictionary

Tags: c#

I am new to C# programming and would some help in solving this linq query.

I want to pull SQL database table into a nested dictionary using linq query where the table ID will be the key in the dictionary and nested dictionary will have other table columns and their respective row entries values.

Example:

```
column1, column2, column3,  column4.....etc
'1',          23,   'abc'    'Loise'
'2',          56,   'def'    'Nary'
'3',          34,   'ghi'    'John'
'4',          67,   'jkl'    'Grace' 


var query = (from d in c.xxxxxxx 
             select d).ToDictionary(s => s.indx);
```

I only care to pull non-null column values.

Comment: What is `C.xxxxxxx`? Why you want to do this at all? Sounds very weird. Why you can't access the properties by their names directly, presuming this is Linq-To-Entities?

Comment: Absolutely correct Rango. Here I am creating an instance of the entity. Don't go by code if incorrect

Comment: You need a GroupBy : Dictionary<string, DataRow> query = c.GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("column1"), y => y).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());